# How to find best time a person opens email

Tags: r, email

I have a dataset that contains details as follows:

```
campaignID, emailAddress, sendDatetime, openDatetime
A           a@x.com       20151001-1000 20151001-1005
A           b@y.com       20151001-1000 20151001-1230
B           a@x.com       20151007-1000 20151007-1100
B           b@y.com       20151007-1000 20151007-1235
```

Using R, how can I find the earliest open time for each individual email address? The output should be:

```
emailAddress, openTime
a@x.com,      10
b@z.com,      12
```

Comment: Aggregate by individual, then make histogram of openDatetime and find mean value, variation, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use data.table.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'emailAddress', we get the `min` of the 'openDatetime' after converting to `POSIXlt` class and then extract the `hour`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(openTime=min(as.POSIXlt(openDatetime, 
                    format= '%Y%m%d-%H%M'))$hour), by = emailAddress]
#  emailAddress openTime
#1:      a@x.com       10
#2:      b@y.com       12
```